# Creando funciones en Rstudio

Tags: r

A partir del siguiente vector:

```
        Lagos <- c(41,72,8,93,4,37,73,190,45,22,19)
```

Quiero crear una función que muestre en la consola la media y la desviación estándar de ese vector y que opcionalmente pueda cambiar la media por la mediana

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
     Lakers <- function(x){
                r <- mean(x) 
                s <- sd(x)
                t <- median(x)
                print(r)
                print(s)
                print(t)
                     }
```

La función responde correctamente pero el gran problema es que no se como indicarle a esa funcion que OPCIONALMENTE cambie la media por la mediana

Si podrían ayudarme a mejorarla por favor, les agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que la función, o bien imprima la media o bien la mediana. Una posibilidad es hacer esto:

```
Lagos <- c(41,72,8,93,4,37,73,190,45,22,19) 

Lakers <- function(x, fun=mean){
    r <- fun(x) 
    s <- sd(x)
    print(r)
    print(s)
}
# La media la invoco de esta forma
Lakers(Lagos)
Lakers(Lagos, mean)

# La mediana  la invoco así
Lakers(Lagos, median)
```

Comment: Perfecto gracias